# Taxonomy custom - struggling to show ACF field

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I'll try to summarize my issue.

I'm templating a taxonomy-job_sector.php - attached to a custom post type called "job".

I would like to get a list of all my terms from this taxonomy "job_sector".

I attached a background-image (with ACF field) to each entry.

[The result i would obtain to display the terms of my taxonomy with custom image for each job sector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy9ca.png)

I don't know how to do this.

I managed to get my term list with the following code  :

```
<?php $wcatTerms = get_terms('job_sector', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' =>0)); 
           foreach($wcatTerms as $wcatTerm) : 
           ?>


        <ul>
           <li>
              <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wcatTerm->slug, $wcatTerm->taxonomy ); ?>"><?php echo $wcatTerm->name; ?></a>
              <ul class="megaSubCat">
                 <?php
                    $wsubargs = array(
                       'hierarchical' => 1,
                       'show_option_none' => '',
                       'hide_empty' => 0,
                       'parent' => $wcatTerm->term_id,
                       'taxonomy' => 'job_sector'
                    );
                    $wsubcats = get_categories($wsubargs);
                    foreach ($wsubcats as $wsc):
                    ?>
                 <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wsc->slug, $wsc->taxonomy );?>"><?php echo $wsc->name;?></a></li>
                 <?php
                    endforeach;
                    ?>  
              </ul>

           </li>
        </ul>
        <?php 
           endforeach; 
           ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_field('field_name', $term_obj);` function passing it as the second parameter the object term of the taxonomy.
For more info check this:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/